# Why input field loses reference to initial array after mapping?

Tags: angular

I have input:

```
@Input() field: LayerField;
```

The I try to load data and apply this data to field:

```
  ngOnInit() {
        if (!this.fieldManager.fieldHasDatasource(this.field)) {
            this.fieldManager.loadSource(this.field).subscribe((source) => {
                this.field = this.fieldManager.setSource(this.field, source);
                this.fieldManager.setValue(this.field);
            });
        }
    }
```

Problem is on the line:

```
this.field = this.fieldManager.setSource(this.field, source);
```

Here I try to update reference `this.field` using serrvice methods:

```
setSource(field: LayerField, source: FieldSource[]): LayerField {
    const reduced = this.reduceSource(source, field.htmlInputAttr.sort_field);
    const sorted = this.sortSource(reduced);

    return { ...field, datasource: { values: sorted } };
}

private reduceSource(source: FieldSource[], sortFieldId: string) {
    return source.map((field) => {
        return {
            ...field,
            sortby: field.classifierrecordfields.find((_field) => _field.classifierfielddefinitionid === sortFieldId)?.numbervalue || 0,
        };
    });
}

sortSource(source: FieldSource[], sortOrder = 'asc'): FieldSource[] {
    return source.sort((a, b) => (sortOrder === 'asc' ? a.sortby - b.sortby : b.sortby - a.sortby));
}
```

Why this way loses reference to input `this.field`? So, parent component does not see this mapped field.

**The code below works for me. Could you explain why?It solves my issue.**

```
  if (this.type === 'select' && !this.fieldManager.fieldHasDatasource(this.field)) {
            this.fieldManager.loadSource(this.field).subscribe((source) => {
                source = this.fieldManager.setSource(source, this.field?.htmlInputAttr?.sort_field);
                source = this.fieldManager.sortSource(source);
                this.field.datasource = { values: source, loaded: true };
                this.field.value = this.field?.htmlInputAttr?.default_value;
            });
        }
```

Service is:

```
setSource(source: FieldSource[], sortFieldId: string): FieldSource[] {
    return source.map((field) => {
        return {
            ...field,
            sortby: field.classifierrecordfields.find((_field) => _field.classifierfielddefinitionid === sortFieldId)?.numbervalue || 0,
        };
    });
}

sortSource(source: FieldSource[], sortOrder = 'asc'): FieldSource[] {
    return source.sort((a, b) => (sortOrder === 'asc' ? a.sortby - b.sortby : b.sortby - a.sortby));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new array reference when using map, and when you use the spread operator (...) you are creating a new object reference that is being returned. So in the end you have a new array reference with each item having a new shallow copied reference.
Instead of creating a new shallow clone you can include an optional property in your FieldSource model with a sortBy?: number.

Then use this value in the map like this.

```
return source.map((field) => {
    field.sortby = field.classifierrecordfields.find((_field) => _field.classifierfielddefinitionid === sortFieldId)?.numbervalue || 0,
    return field;
});
```